# How to display objects of a a class?

Tags: java, class, object

I'm working on a practice project, movie store system. How can I display the objects of class `Movie`? Class `Movie` has all the `movie`, `movie1`, `movie2`.

Also, how can I select a movie, and use only one method? For example, I select `movie1`, then I will execute the method. `movie1.dispMovie()`, or should I make the method launch manually?

```
public class movie {

private String name;
private String desc;
private int year;

public static int movieNum = 0;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public int getYear() {
    return year;
}
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public void dispdesc(){

    movieNum = movieNum + 1;

    System.out.println("Movie #" + movieNum);
    System.out.println("Title: " + getName());
    System.out.println("Description: " + getDesc());
    System.out.println("Year: " + getYear());
}
}


public class orangeBox {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    movie up = new movie();
    up.setName("Up");
    up.setDesc("To avoid being taken away to a nursing home, an old widower tries to fly his home to Paradise Falls, South America, along with a boy scout who accidently lifted off with him. ");
    up.setYear(2008);
    up.dispdesc();

    movie wallE = new movie();
    wallE.setName("Wall-E");
    wallE.setDesc("In the distant future, a small waste collecting robot inadvertently embarks on a space journey that will ultimately decide the fate of mankind.");
    wallE.setYear(2008);
    wallE.dispdesc();

}

}
```

I need a method that will display all the movie without doing this.dispdesc() in the main class.

**EDIT**

```
public class Store {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Movie up = new Movie();
    up.setName("Up");
    up.setDesc("To avoid being taken away...");
    up.setYear(2009);

    System.out.println(up);

}

}
```

Comment: [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Have I *misunderstood* the question?

Comment: @TheLostMind I think it was me.. :/ I'm not sure

Comment: @Rakken - Show us the expected output..

Comment: I've added the code, and the thing i need below.

Comment: @TheLostMind I've added the code and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several bad practices in your code.

1) Conventions : Classes will be written with an upper case letter.

2) Movie should be a data-type only. Calling `System.out` within this class is bad, because if you would have a larger project, there are too many (and widespread) places to make changes, if you would consider changing the output system. Consider overriding the `toString` method and build your return String in the desired format with `\n` and `\t` and so on.

System.out will be called from the main e.g.

3) for numbering consider the static number movieNum to be increased in the constructor! As you should consider a constructor, which accepts all necessary attributes.

4) To save multiple Movie-Objects save them within a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (possibly ArrayList)

**EDIT**

for 2)

As i mentioned, it is "bad practice" meaning, it is considered a-not-so-good way of accomplishing things, even though they work.

Imagine you have 100+ classes which are similar to your Movie-Class. In mid-sized projects it is standard to have at least 100 classes which sole purpose is to save data. Now imagine in each is at least 1 `System.out` statement. After some time you dont want to have an ugly console output but want to move to a GUI-library (e.g. Swing). Then you can trash each `System.out` statement in each of these classes. Since there are enourmous amout of classes it takes A LONG time to adjust these and since they are widespread it is easy to miss some. Maybe you need other changes too. It is easier to decouple data-types (e.g. Movie, or a possible Store class and so on) and io-logic (e.g. your main).

Again : your approach works fine too, however if you want to start a more complex project (e.g. a game of some sorts, or soemthing else) it is easier to do it the right way from the start. Then you can more easily change crucial parts of the project (as e.g. the input/output framework aka GUI)

The usual way to output your Objects would be either (usually on GUI) to get the attributes you want (via `getter`) and display on labels and so on or to override the `toString` method which has every objects (since all classes implicitly extends the class Object).

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   String s = "Movie #\t"+getMovieNumber()+ "\n";  // \n is a linebreak and \t is indention
   s += "Title: \t"+getName()+"\n";
   s += "Description: \t"+getDescription()+"\n";
   s += "Year: \t"+getYear();
   return s;
}
```

(Consider using `StringBuilder` class here instead of building String with `+=`. Used it just for simplicity only.)

If you have this snippet in your Movie class and a suitible constructor you can do in the main :

```
Movie up = new Movie("Up", "To avoid being taken away....", 2008 );
System.out.println(up);
```

**Edit2**

for 3)

```
private static int movieNum = 0;

public Movie() {
    movieNum++;
}
```

Comment: As a beginner, I can only understand 1, 3 and maybe 4. Can I ask for a more hmm, beginner-friendly explanation for 2?

Comment: Hmm, I can't say that I quite understand the whole thing yet. Though I get that this code is better since I will be moving this up to GUI at some point. Can you explain the toString()? And, what does @Override does? Does it override an existing method/function?

Comment: `@Override` is an annotation. You dont actually need it, but its standard and some frameworks might work with these. You should always add it, if you are overriding a method, but usually you wont run into problems without it (in my experience). `toString()` is inherited from the class `Object`. When you call `System.out.println(objectx)` you implicitly call `System.out.println(objectx.toString())`. In the default implementation in `Object`it returns the adresse reference of the object. However you can override it to present the key values of the object instead

Comment: furthermore it is okay, that you dont understand it the first time. You will eventually as time passes. But its good to remember the "good practices" earlier, so that "bad practices" does get extinguished earlier.

Comment: I maybe now understand it, but not fully. I added a code for main class. Can you check it out?

Comment: well, if you override the toString method, it should be fine. Also do 1) and 3)

Comment: On 1, should all be classes be made with a capital letter? How about the objects, should they be created with uppercase letter too?

Last question, thanks for sticking with me. I understand the concept of 3, but I just don't know how to implement it. How can I add to the static int on the constructor?

Comment: on 1: plz look into http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_quick_guide.htm , for 3 : the way you already did it. Just increase the number in the constructor instead of the `dispdesc` method

Comment: 3, I don't understand. Please give me an example code on how to add on the variable in the constructor.

Comment: I understand it now, it seems that I don't have a constructor on my class Movie. Please confirm, I can create a class and run it without a constructor method, is that why my class Movie without a constructor compiled? Here's my new code [link](http://pastebin.com/mxQEdZDk)

Comment: the empty constructor (constructor without params) is always implicitly there, however you can just write it too and fill it with useful infos (like increasing thestatic number, or initialize Lists and so on)

Comment: I added a link on my previous comment, did I do it right?

Comment: what's the other way? I'd like to see different ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Arraylist<movie> myMovieList =new ArrayList<movie>();

movie up = new movie();
up.setName("Up");
up.setDesc("To avoid being taken away to a nursing home, an old widower tries to fly his home to Paradise Falls, South America, along with a boy scout who accidently lifted off with him. ");
up.setYear(2008);
myMovieList.add(up)

movie wallE = new movie();
wallE.setName("Wall-E");
wallE.setDesc("In the distant future, a small waste collecting robot inadvertently embarks on a space journey that will ultimately decide the fate of mankind.");
wallE.setYear(2008);
myMovieList.add(wallE)

 dispdesc(myMovieList);
}

public void dispdesc(ArrayList<movie> movieList){

for(movie object : movieList)
{
 movieNum = movieNum + 1;

System.out.println("Movie #" + movieNum);
System.out.println("Title: " + getName());
System.out.println("Description: " + getDesc());
System.out.println("Year: " + getYear()); 
} 
}
```

Comment: If for example, if possible, I will create a new object on runtime, (is it possible to make object on runtime, in the future, I would like to make it a system where in there's a GUI, and an option to add a new movie to the list) would the structure of the code will change?

Comment: Yes it will be change according to your needs.but the case you mentioned no need to change it you add object at run time to the global arrayList for your objects once added you need to call dispdesc at last .

Comment: Question, where is the method add(x)?

Comment: you can create add method inside your global controller class that communicate with your UI

Comment: I might have created a misunderstanding, I still haven't learned UI, JFrame, I just asked it since I might have to change it in the future, but for now, I'll be doing it on the console. I did this project before in C as a project for our Introduction to Programming course, I'm trying to recreate in Java, since our next course is about OOP.

Comment: ok keep it now. and forget about ui for now.
you will first digest these concept then moves further.